# Google Maps - folded paper effect, how?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a website where I've included a Google Map using the Google Maps API v3. Now I'm wondering how to make the map look like a "real map" (one out of paper that has been folded), like this one:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yRuz5FO7T9k/TvM0yUAXQ5I/AAAAAAAAM0Y/uLB3oG6R8OI/s523/mapsmania.gif

The user must still be able to interact with the map, so I can't just put a "paper looking" div on top of the map and set opacity to some low number.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Preferably with css.

Answer (score 2):

this screenshot is taken from http://www.ubilabs.net/kontakt

It's a simple map which is covered  by a `<div/>` with a semi-transparent background-image(http://www.ubilabs.net/images/map_overlay.png)

To be able to interact with the map the `pointer-events`-style of this div is set to `none`

Comment: Nice! The only problem with this is that the overlay doesn't move when you move the map, making it look a bit weird. Is it possible to make it look like the overlay moves with the map?