# Google Map is static after adding transparency image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I added a transparency image to my google map, and it looks fine, but now I can't click on the map to move it or zoom in and I can't click on the markers. What's weird, though, is I can actually move the map and click on markers but only if I click on the very very outer edges of the map. I've fiddled with all the code and can't seem to get it to work properly. When the map layer moves to front is the only time I can really use the map, but then the transparency disappears... any feedback would be appreciated...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Map</title> 
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<center>
<p>
<div id="map" style="height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: -200px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border-bottom-width:77px;
border-bottom-color:black;
border-bottom-style: solid;
z-index: -1;"></div>

<script src="scripts/mapmarkers.js"></script>

<p>
<div align="left"><img src="images/transimage.png" width="500" height="550" /></div>
```

Comment: Why is it weird? Would be weird when it's raining, you carry an umbrella and you stay dry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - folded paper effect, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707937/google-maps-folded-paper-effect-how)

Comment: Holy Molle!!! Thanks, doc. But I was hoping this was possible without css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that worked:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 3%; top: 0%;">
<img src="image.png" width="50" height="50"></div>
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to explain why your solution worked.