# how to apply unfold the google map on mouseover event occurs in html site

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I want to apply paper folding effects for g map using latitude and longitude. when the mouse over function occurs unfold the map otherwise fold the map.

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: Then look at their source code.

Comment: @paulitto It seems to work occasionally. I had to try twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - folded paper effect, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707937/google-maps-folded-paper-effect-how)

Comment: Basically the Google maps is enclosed within a div.  The fold and unfold happens to to the div.  Here is a tutorial http://codepen.io/boxabrain/pen/Hhugb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create a static map that would duplicate zoom/center or even markers of the usual google map and make all css transforms with it on `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

You can use [oridomi](http://oridomi.com/) with lots of cool paper fold effects, which would make it much easier

here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/2hk0z2nu/) to show the idea